# How to print questions on different pages, navigate between them keeping the database updated in an online examination portal?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, radio-button

Here's my question:
I am creating an online examination portal. There's a database from where questions with their respective 4 options are fetched randomly. It is an MCQ based exam with **one question on one page.**

The page contains following buttons:

```
   NEXT, PREVIOUS, SUBMIT, FINISH EXAM
```

I want to record the selected radio button every time user clicks submit.

The part where I am stuck:

How to record the selected option and at the same time user should be redirected to page containing next question?
Right now I am looping through the output array given by SQL query and printing questions one by one on a single page.

Generating the random value:

```
    $offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `question` WHERE cat_id = '$category'
    AND difficulty_level= '$difficulty_level'
    AND subcat_id = '$subcategory' ");
```

Fetching questions:

```
    $result1 = mysql_query( " SELECT `question`, `ans1`, `ans2`, `ans3`,
    `ans4`,`correct_ans`  FROM `question`             
    WHERE cat_id = '$category'
    AND difficulty_level= '$difficulty_level'
    AND subcat_id = '$subcategory' LIMIT $offset, 5");
```

LOOP:

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
    {
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1> <?php print_r($row[0]) ?> </h1> //prints question

    <div class="options-radio">

    <span><?php print_r($row[1]) ?></span> <input class="radio" type="radio" name="A" value="<?php print_r($row[3]) ?>" />  //prints option 1 and so on
   <br>
    <span><?php print_r($row[2]) ?></span> <input class="radio" type="radio" name="B" value="<?php print_r($row[4]) ?>" /> 
   <br>
   <span><?php print_r($row[3]) ?></span> <input class="radio" type="radio" name="C" value="<?php print_r($row[5]) ?>" /> 
   <br>
   <span><?php print_r($row[4]) ?></span> <input class="radio" type="radio" name="D" value="<?php print_r($row[6]) ?>" /> 
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"   onclick="javascript:SubmitFrm()">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  </html>
    </body>
```

Maybe someone could suggest a better method for printing individual questions on different pages. Plus how to navigate between pages keeping the database updated every time user clicks the submit. Thanks in advance.